# Is there a way to write this if-else using min and max?

Tags: python

This is the condition.

```
 if (car.y < 100): car.y = 100
 if (car.y + car.height) > 500: car.y = 500 - car.height
```

I want to know how to write this using min and max.

This is what I tried.

```
car.y = max(100, min(500, car.y - car.height))
```

According to my knowledge, `min(500, car.y - car.height)` returns 500 if `500 < car.y - car.height`, which means it cant ever be more than 500, capping the upper limit and since its in `max(100, ...)`, the lower value cant be less than 100.

I used this test and everything works as expected. The values are capped between 100 and 500.

```
for i in range(100):
    print(max(100, min(500, random.randint(10,  1000) - random.randint(10, 1000))))
```

Now here is where I am stuck.

In the following case.

```
y = 100
height = 10  
while True:
    if (y < 100): y = 100
    if (y + height) > 500: y = 500 - height
    y += 1
    print(y)
```

It behaves as expected but in the following case:

```
y = 100
height = 10

while True:
    y = max(100, min(500, y - height))
    y += 1
    print(y)
```

It just prints 101 continuously and doesn't increment at all. It's stuck at 101. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to run this code (I have used a for loop rather than a **while** to make it more testable):

```
y = 100
height = 10

for i in range(5):
    h = min(500, y - height)
    y = max(100, h)
    print(h , ' ' , y , ' ', y+1, '\n')
    y += 1
```

You will see that it gets stuck at **101**. Why? Let's do the iteration together:

### Loop 1

`h` is **min** between 500 and (100-10), thus it will be 90

`y` is **max** between 100 and 90, so it will be 100

`y` is plus 1, which now becomes 101

### Loop 2

`h` is **min** between 500 and (101-10), so 91

`y` is **max** between 100 and 91, so? 100!

`y` is plus 1, so 100 + 1 now becomes **101**... and this will continue forever, let's continue just to prove this:

### Loop 3

`h` is **min** between 500 and (101-10), so 91

`y` is **max** between 100 and 91... 100!

`y` is plus 1, **101...**

So as you can see, as the product of y will remain 101, no matter how many times we try, it will remain 101 in the end.

Now you know why it got stuck. Depending on what you need to do or what you are experimenting on, you can add **another** variable, allowing **y** to freely grow and make your code work as expected:

```
y = 100
height = 10

for i in range(25):
    h = min(500, y - height)
    z = max(100, h)
    y += 1
    print(h , ' ' , z , ' ', y, '\n')
```

And convert the for loop into a while as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Blue_notes answer just the other way round.

```
car.y = max(car.y, 100);
car.y = min(car.y, 500-car.height)
```

or if you want it as one line

```
car.y = min(max(car.y, 100),500 - car.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = 100
height = 10  
while True:
    if (y < 100): y = 100
    if (y + height) > 500: y = 500 - height
    y += 1
    print(y)
```

Snippet above makes it stuck at 491. Similar code in max min style is below:

```
y = 100 
height = 10 
while True: 
    y = min(500-height, max(100, y)) + 1
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum that `car.y` can be is `500 - car.height` (so you need to select the smaller of the two). The minimum that it can be is `100` (so you need to select the larger of this pair)

```
car.y = max(min(car.y, 500 - car.height), 100)
```